# Updated to 14.04, can't connect to the wireless network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

So I dug out my 5+ year old netbook, and updated the Ubuntu to release 14.04 (from 10.04) and now it can see the wireless connection and it says it connects to it, but it does not load any pages in the browser, nor does it load the router's site either. I can connect via ethernet.

Please note that I'm a linux newb, I only know to post these commands from googling this problem and seeing that other people posted them - please let me know if there's anything else I should post as well, and if you could explain solutions like I'm a 5-year-old, it'd probably help out a lot!

**Solutions I've already tried:**

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

sudo iwconfig

```
wlan0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"aterm-f78fa8-g"
         Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 10:66:82:4D:34:DC
         Bit Rate=26 Mb/s  Tx-Power=200 dBm
         Retry  long limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
         Encryption key:off
         Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-22 dBm
         Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt: 0  Rx invalid frag:0
         Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0  Missed beacon:0

lo       no wireless extensions

eth0     no wireless extensions
```

sudo lspci -v

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adaptor (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device 7179
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) {size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
        Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-9f-ff-ff-52-b4-74
        Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: wl
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
*-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8101E/RTL8102EPCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
        logical name: eth0
        version: 05
        serial: e8:11:32:2c:5c:d6
        size: 10Mbit/s
        capacity: 100Mbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
        resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f050c000-f050cfff memory:f0508000-f050bfff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `iwconfig` output doesn't say anything about power management. Try following:

1. Launch terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and write:
   `sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
2. `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`
4. copy paste following into the opened file:
   `!/bin/sh 
   /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power on`
5. Save the file and close gedit.
6. `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to restart NetworkManager. Try `sudo service network-manager restart` once. It may only be a temporary solution (most likely), or it may work permanently for some reason. (I don't know, maybe networkmanager just needs to be woken up?